# Renaming duplicate files in a folder with php

Tags: php

Who can help me to fix the following problem? Here is the issue: in a form POST i made people can upload files. The code below check if in the "uploads" folder there another file with the same name. If so, files are renamed as this example:

```
hallo.txt
1_hallo.txt
2_hallo.txt
```

... and so on.

This is the code used:

```
$OriginalFilename = $FinalFilename = $_FILES['uploaded']['name'];
// rename file if it already exists by prefixing an incrementing number
$FileCounter = 1;
while (file_exists( 'uploads/'.$FinalFilename ))
$FinalFilename = $FileCounter++.'_'.$OriginalFilename;
```

I would like to rename files in a different way. progressive numbers should be AFTER the file and, of course, before the extention. This is the same example of before but in the way i want:

```
hallo.txt
hallo_1.txt
hallo_2.txt
```

... and so on.

How can i modify the code to reach that result?
Thank you in advance and sorry for my newbie-style question. I'm really newbie! :)

Mat

Comment: Just switch around the string concatenation? Unless I'm missing something.

Comment: @EvanMulawski yep, the extension

Comment: @DanLee Ah, that was it. I had a feeling it was too simple.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Just change the `$FinalFilename`:

```
$FinalFilename = pathinfo($OriginalFilename, PATHINFO_FILENAME) . '_' . $FileCounter++ . '.' . pathinfo($OriginalFilename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Or (better if you have a lot of files with the same name and often iterate more than once):

```
$filename = pathinfo($OriginalFilename, PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension =  pathinfo($OriginalFilename, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
while (file_exists( 'uploads/'.$FinalFilename ))
    $FinalFilename = $filename . '_' . $FileCounter++ . '.' . $extension;
```

Comment: Thank you so much. I already tested the two suggestions but in both cases new files have something missing in the extention. If i use the 1st line, extentions are completely missing. In the second code, duplicate files are stored with no points between filenames and extentions. :)

Comment: @mattew Ah yes, I forgot to put the `.` in both of them. They should work now :)

Comment: Yes yes, thanks so much, indeed i found the missing "." in the code and now works perfectly!! I decided to use the 2nd code you suggested. You're really great. Thank you!!!