# Rename a file if already exists - php upload system

Tags: php, file, upload, exists

I this PHP code:

```
<?php

// Check for errors
if($_FILES['file_upload']['error'] > 0){
    die('An error ocurred when uploading.');
}

if(!getimagesize($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'])){
    die('Please ensure you are uploading an image.');
}

// Check filesize
if($_FILES['file_upload']['size'] > 500000){
    die('File uploaded exceeds maximum upload size.');
}

// Check if the file exists
if(file_exists('upload/' . $_FILES['file_upload']['name'])){
    die('File with that name already exists.');
}

// Upload file
if(!move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file_upload']['tmp_name'], 'upload/' . $_FILES['file_upload']['name'])){
    die('Error uploading file - check destination is writeable.');
}

die('File uploaded successfully.');

?>
```

and I need to act like a "windows" kind of treatment for existing files - I mean the if the file exists, i want it to be changed to the name of the file with the number 1 after it.

for example: myfile.jpg is already exists, so if you'll upload it again it will be myfile1.jpg, and if myfile1.jpg exists, it will be myfile11.jpg and so on...

how can i do it? i tried some loops but unfortunately without success.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Renaming duplicate files in a folder with php](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068093/renaming-duplicate-files-in-a-folder-with-php)

Answer (score 15):

You could do something like this:

```
$name = pathinfo($_FILES['file_upload']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file_upload']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

// add a suffix of '1' to the file name until it no longer conflicts
while(file_exists($name . '.' . $extension)) {
    $name .= '1';
}

$basename = $name . '.' . $extension;
```

To avoid very long names, it would probably be neater to append a number, e.g. `file1.jpg`, `file2.jpg` etc:

```
$name = pathinfo($_FILES['file_upload']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file_upload']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);

$increment = ''; //start with no suffix

while(file_exists($name . $increment . '.' . $extension)) {
    $increment++;
}

$basename = $name . $increment . '.' . $extension;
```

Comment: and how can i do that? :)

Comment: I've added an example.

Comment: Mr.George, I tried  your second code , In that $increment++ is not working.Can you help me in this

Comment: @Hybreeder Please elaborate on "not working" - any errors?

Comment: e.g.I uploaded first file name is demo.png and second time i uploaded same file name demo.png and it renamed by demo1.png.there is no issue in this but when i uploaded same file third time then nothing is happening.I haven't got demo2.png....Please help me in this.

Answer (score 1):

For user6930268;
i think your code should be:

```
$name = pathinfo($_FILES['file_upload']['name'], PATHINFO_FILENAME);
$extension = pathinfo($_FILES['file_upload']['name'], PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
$dirname = pathinfo($_FILES['file_upload']['name'], PATHINFO_DIRNAME);
$dirname = $dirname. "/";
$increment = ''; //start with no suffix

while(file_exists($dirname . $name . $increment . '.' . $extension)) {
    $increment++;
}

$basename = $name . $increment . '.' . $extension;
$resultFilePath = $dirname . $name . $increment . '.' . $extension);
```

Answer (score 0):

1. You uploaded a file called `demo.png`.
2. You tried to upload the same file `demo.png` and it got renamed to `demo2.png`.
3. When you try to upload `demo.png` for 3rd time, it gets renamed to `demo1.png` once again and replaces the file you upload in (2).

so you won't find `demo3.png`

Answer (score 0):

Here is a my function i'm using. It will generate file (1).txt , file (2).txt , file ...

```
function getFilePathUnique($path) {

    while ($this->location->fileExists($path)) {

        $info = pathInfo($path);

        //extract the current number of file
        preg_match("/\([0-9]+\)$/",$info["filename"], $number);
        $number = str_replace(["(" , ")"] , ["" , ""] , $number[0]);

        //remove the old number
        $info["filename"] = trim(preg_replace( "/\([0-9]+\)$/" , "" , $info["filename"] ));

        //append new number
        $info["filename"] .= " (" . (++$number) . ")";

        //build path
        $path = ($info["dirname"] != "." ? $info["dirname"]:  "" ).
            $info["filename"] . "." . $info["extension"];
    }           

    return $path;
    
}
```