# PHP Overwrite Uploaded Image

Tags: php, file-upload

I am trying some  file upload code which I Googled.

Now Issue is when I try to upload image and if its already in folder then its over write and issues come. I Try Code From [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18972518/rename-a-file-if-already-exists-php-upload-system) and [here as well](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16136519/php-rename-file-name-if-exists-append-number-to-end) but I face some error.

Here is my code. Can I do in this code that its upload file with some extra name which stop over write of existing file??

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['main']))
{

    $allowedExts = array("gif", "jpeg", "jpg", "png");
      $temp = explode(".", $_FILES["file"]["name"]);
      $extension = end($temp);

      /*if ((($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/jpg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/x-png") || ($_FILES["file"]["type"] == "image/png")) && ($_FILES["file"]["size"] < 20000) && in_array($extension, $allowedExts))  {*/

        if ($_FILES["file"]["error"] > 0) {
            echo "Return Code: " . $_FILES["file"]["error"] . "<br>";
        } else {

            if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
                echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
            } else {
                if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/catalog/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]) ){
                    $filepath = "img/catalog/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                }else{
                    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"]." unable to store";
                }
            }
        /*}
      } else {
        echo "Invalid file";
      }*/
}
    $main = $_REQUEST['main'];
    $sql="INSERT INTO image VALUES ('', '$filepath', '$main')";

    if (!mysqli_query($con,$sql)) {
      die('Error: ' . mysqli_error($con));
    }
    echo "1 record added";
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check if the file exists using [`file_exists`](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.file-exists.php).

If it exist, add some extra characters to the file name. Then you can save it.

Here is a function that generates random characters :

```
function randomString($length) {
 $str="";
 $chars = "subinsblogabcdefghijklmanopqrstuvwxyzABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZ0123456789";
 $size = strlen($chars);
 for($i = 0;$i < $length;$i++) {
  $str .= $chars[rand(0,$size-1)];
 }
 return $str;
}
```

Replace the code :

```
if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/catalog/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]) ){
  $filepath = "img/catalog/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
}else{
   echo $_FILES["file"]["name"]." unable to store";
}
```

with :

```
$newLocation = "../img/catalog/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
if(file_exists($newLocation)){
   $newLocation .= randomString(10); // We append 10 new characters
}

if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], $newLocation) ){
   $filepath = str_replace("../img", "img", $newLocation); // make File Path starting with img/
}else{
   echo $_FILES["file"]["name"]." unable to store";
}
```

The above code will check if the file exists. If yes, then a string of **10 random characters** is appended to the file name and stored in the destination folder.

Answer (score 0):

You didnt mention your problem but I think you have missed a point in your

> if else

part. write it like this :

```
   if (file_exists("upload/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"])) {
            echo $_FILES["file"]["name"] . " already exists. ";
$_FILES["file"]["name"] = $_FILES["file"]["name"].$your_new_number;
            }
                if( move_uploaded_file($_FILES["file"]["tmp_name"], "../img/catalog/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"]) ){
                    $filepath = "img/catalog/" . $_FILES["file"]["name"];
                }else{
                    echo $_FILES["file"]["name"]." unable to store";
                }
            }
```