# how to rename uploaded files if there's duplicated names

Tags: php, upload

i'm having a small issue in the duplicated names.
I want to auto rename any duplicated upload files, like numbering them.

or if i could make the name same with numbers, such as file1.jpg / file2.jpg
for all uploaded files

here's my code

```html
<?php

 include('connect-db.php');
  
 if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
  

$filename=  $_FILES["imgfile"]["name"];
  if ((($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/gif")|| ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/png")  || ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && ($_FILES["imgfile"]["size"] < 20000000))



  {
    if(file_exists($_FILES["imgfile"]["name"]))
    {
      echo "File name exists.";
    }

    else
    {
      move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgfile"]["tmp_name"],"photos/$filename");
    }


  }
 

  if (is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
   $id = $_POST['id'];
   
   $id_photo= mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['filename']));

   // check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in
   
   if ($filename== '' ) {
    // generate error message
    $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>"); //Refresh by HTTP META

   } else {
    // save the data to the database
    mysql_query("UPDATE table SET id_photo='$filename' WHERE id='$id' ") or die(mysql_error());
    // once saved, redirect back to the view page

echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>"); //Refresh by HTTP META

   }

  } else {
   // if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
   echo 'Error!';
  }
 
 }
 
 
 ?>
```

Even the echo of if(file_exists($_FILES["imgfile"]["name"])) it's not working, i don't know why

Thank you very much before replying

Comment: you want to rename uploading file???

Answer (score 1):

try this code 
**this code will never get same name this code will rename file like `2jh5425h44u5h45h454k5image.jpg`  this is how it will save file** so no need to worry about duplicate file
i have added random name generator `$newname = md5(rand() * time());` this will generate random name for your file

```
    <?php

include('connect-db.php');
$newname = md5(rand() * time());
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $filename = $_FILES["imgfile"]["name"];
    if ((($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/gif") || ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/jpeg") || ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/png") || ($_FILES["imgfile"]["type"] == "image/pjpeg")) && ($_FILES["imgfile"]["size"] < 20000000)) {
        if (file_exists($_FILES["imgfile"]["name"])) {
            echo "File name exists.";
        } else {
            move_uploaded_file($_FILES["imgfile"]["tmp_name"], "photos/$newname . $filename");
        }
    }
    if (is_numeric($_POST['id'])) {
        $id = $_POST['id'];

        $id_photo = mysql_real_escape_string(htmlspecialchars($_POST['filename']));

        // check that firstname/lastname fields are both filled in

        if ($filename == '') {
            // generate error message
            $error = 'ERROR: Please fill in all required fields!';

            echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>"); //Refresh by HTTP META
        } else {
            // save the data to the database
            mysql_query("UPDATE table SET id_photo='$filename' WHERE id='$id' ") or die(mysql_error());
            // once saved, redirect back to the view page

            echo("<meta http-equiv='refresh' content='0'>"); //Refresh by HTTP META
        }
    } else {
        // if the 'id' isn't valid, display an error
        echo 'Error!';
    }
}
?>
```

if you need to rename only if file is duplicate here is answer [Renaming duplicate files in a folder with php](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11068093/renaming-duplicate-files-in-a-folder-with-php)